# How can I programmatically save a RDLC file to open in future

Tags: c#, rdlc

Im doing my first project with C# and I need my program automatically save a RDLC file to re-open it, with the data, when requisited. It's a "Receipt Report" that I need to keep stored. What the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be pretty straight forward, you should be able to get what you need through Google search...

You may reference the following code and expand on it.

```
string strmimeType = "", encoding, fileNameExtension = "";
string[] streamIds;
Warning[] warning;

//Other Code Here...

byte[] bytes = ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out strmimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streamIds, out warning);

//Save to file
string filePath = @"C:\someTempFolder\temp" + fileNameExtension;
FileStream FileObject = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
FileObject.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
FileObject.Close();
```